# Units of damping terms for harmonic oscillator

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, units

I understand that in the equation of motion of a simple harmonic oscillator $\ddot{x} + \omega_0^2 x = 0$, $\omega_0$ has dimension inverse time.  Since solutions are of the form $x(t) = A \cos (\omega_0 t + \phi)$, I also understand that $\omega_0$ is an angular frequency, and is often expressed in units of rad/s.

Now if we add a viscous damping term, the equation of motion can be written as $\ddot{x} + \gamma \dot{x} + \omega_0^2 x = 0$.  The dimensions of $\gamma$ are again an inverse time, but I am confused about its units, in other words is it a frequency or an angular frequency?

I know for instance that the solutions will be proportional to $e^{-\gamma t/2}$, and that makes me think the units of $\gamma$ are /s, but I am not sure.  On the other hand, the quality factor is $\omega_0/ \gamma$.

In practice, if I apply this to a series RLC circuit, $\gamma = R/L$ is an inverse time, but for $R$ in Ohms, and $L$ in Henries, do we get /s or rad/s?

Answer (score 2):

$\gamma$ is not a frequency or an angular frequency (although it has the same units, 1/s). Think of $1/\gamma$ as relaxation time.

As concerns the second part of your question, just look up Henries and Ohms in SI units and work your way from there on.

Edit (after @Mister Mak's comment): To clarify the difference between frequency and angular frequency, between rad/s and 1/s.
Rad is of course dimensionless and not that much of a physical dimension. Well, it is, as I just learnt from Wikipedia^^, but $1\,$rad $= 1$, you know... It's just giving you context to say that angles are involved somehow.

A pendulum oscillating with a frequency $f$ reaches the same state after a time $T=1/f$. Describing its trajectory with a sine you have
$$
x\left(t\right) = \sin\left(2 \pi f t\right)
$$
wherein it may be convenient to use the angular frequency $\omega = 2 \pi f$, just as a shorter notation.
As concerns $\gamma$ in your example of a damped pendulum, it is not used in a sine, not describing an oscillation or a periodic process, so there is no point in measuring it in rad/s. I mean, you could, but that would be pointless, a bit like selling $4\,$rad eggs.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  The second point doesn't really clarify things: for a pendulum, neither $g$ nor $l$ have radians in them, yet the natural frequency $\omega_0=\sqrt{g/l}$ is expressed in rad/s.

Comment: @Mister Mak: Hope things are clearer after my edit, although after thinking about your question more, they are a bit less clear to me. ^^

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I suspect the answer has to do with whether the solution is periodic (the oscillating, can include an angle) or not (the damping, shouldn't include an angle?).  Not sure what wikipedia entry you are considering, but as far as I know, angles have no dimension as they are a ratio of lengths, but are expressed in units including radians and degrees.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian, quote "The unit was formerly an SI supplementary unit (before that category was abolished in 1995) and the radian is now an SI derived unit."

Answer (score 1):

Radian really has no unit, it is something related to notation. As radians refer to the arclength divided by the full perimeter of a circumference, it has no units. Therefore, it doesn't matter as frequency $f$ is $2\pi w$, so both have the same units ($s^{-1}$).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I agree angles (a ratio of lengths) are dimensionless, but as far as I know, radians are indeed a unit to measure angles (eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian).  Other units for angles include degrees.

Comment: Yes but radians per second is analogous to revolutions per second (frequency). Revolutions is a unit, but as radians, don't have any physical importance. And as you can suppose frequency as $s^{-1}$ and revolutions per second, you can suppose angular frequency as radians per second or $s^{-1}$.